# saving file in alfresco with Version and Download the latest version

Tags: java, alfresco

I work with alfresco Community 4.0 and I used this jar **alfresco-web-service-client-4.0.d.jar**

using this code I can save my test.pdf file in alfresco :

```
File file = new File("C:/test.pdf");

  saveAttachement(file,"test.pdf", "/app:company_home/cm:MyFolder",
                        "admin", "admin")



                         public String saveAttachement(File file, String name, String folderName, String userName, String pwd)
        throws Exception {


        byte[] contentByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));

        // Start the session
        AuthenticationUtils.startSession(userName, pwd);

        try {
            // Create a reference to the parent where we want to create content
            Store storeRef = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "SpacesStore");
            ParentReference companyHomeParent = new ParentReference(storeRef, null, folderName, Constants.ASSOC_CONTAINS, null);

            // Assign name
            companyHomeParent.setChildName("cm:" + name);

            // Construct CML statement to create content node
            // Note: Assign "1" as a local id, so we can refer to it in subsequent
            //       CML statements within the same CML block
            NamedValue[] contentProps = new NamedValue[1];
            contentProps[0] = Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_NAME, name);

            CMLCreate create = new CMLCreate("1", companyHomeParent, null, null, null, Constants.TYPE_CONTENT, contentProps);

            // Construct CML statement to add titled aspect
            NamedValue[] titledProps = new NamedValue[2];
            titledProps[0] = Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_TITLE, name);
            titledProps[1] = Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_DESCRIPTION, name);

            CMLAddAspect addAspect = new CMLAddAspect(Constants.ASPECT_TITLED, titledProps, null, "1");

            // Construct CML Block
            CML cml = new CML();
            cml.setCreate(new CMLCreate[] { create });
            cml.setAddAspect(new CMLAddAspect[] { addAspect });

            // Issue CML statement via Repository Web Service and retrieve result
            // Note: Batching of multiple statements into a single web call
            UpdateResult[] result = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService().update(cml);
            Reference content = result[0].getDestination();

            // Write some content
            ContentServiceSoapBindingStub contentService = WebServiceFactory.getContentService();

            //String text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
            ContentFormat contentFormat = new ContentFormat("text/plain", "UTF-8");
            Content contentRef = contentService.write(content, Constants.PROP_CONTENT, contentByte, contentFormat);
            System.out.println("Document are created successfully. UID:= " + content.getUuid());

            return content.getUuid();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            // End the session
            AuthenticationUtils.endSession();

            //System.exit(0);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

after saving this file in alfresco I have this id `d7633eff-8595-4d6c-8c18-a29a656607ba`

it will be used later to download this file

This is the download code :

```
ContentResult contentResult = getContentsById("d7633eff-8595-4d6c-8c18-a29a656607ba", "admin", "admin");


       public ContentResult getContentsById(String contentId, String userName, String pwd)
        throws Exception {
        ContentResult contentResult = new ContentResult();

        // Start the session
        AuthenticationUtils.startSession(userName, pwd);

        try {
            Store storeRef = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "SpacesStore");
            ContentServiceSoapBindingStub contentService = WebServiceFactory.getContentService();

            Reference contentReference = new Reference(storeRef, contentId, null);
            Content[] readResult = null;

            try {
                readResult = contentService.read(new Predicate(new Reference[] { contentReference }, storeRef, null), Constants.PROP_CONTENT);
            } catch (ContentFault e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if ((readResult != null) && (readResult[0] != null)) {
                Content content = readResult[0];
                ContentFormat cnf = content.getFormat();
                Reference ref = content.getNode();

                String[] splitedUrl = content.getUrl().split("/");
                String name = splitedUrl[splitedUrl.length - 1];

                InputStream is = ContentUtils.getContentAsInputStream(content);
                byte[] contentByte = ConvertUtil.convertInputStreamToByte(is);

                contentResult.setName(name);
                contentResult.setMimetype(cnf.getMimetype());
                contentResult.setId(ref.getUuid());
                contentResult.setUrl(content.getUrl());
                contentResult.setPath(ref.getPath());
                contentResult.setContentByte(contentByte);
                System.out.println(" document has been retrieved");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            // End the session
            AuthenticationUtils.endSession();

            // System.exit(0);
        }

        return contentResult;
    }
```

currently I change the **test.pdf**  file content  without changing the file name
        and I put it in another location in the disc.

This is the new file location.

**C:/version/test.pdf**

So in the disk I have two files with the same name but with different content.

my goal is to save the new file in alfresco but using versioning.

in my opinion I must use the old id  which is saving in alfresco : **d7633eff-8595-4d6c-8c18-a29a656607ba**

so I should develop a method that takes as a parameter the new file and the old id

like this

```
 File file = new File("C:/version/test.pdf");

  saveWithVersionAttachement(file,"d7633eff-8595-4d6c-8c18-a29a656607ba","test.pdf", "/app:company_home/cm:MyFolder",
                        "admin", "admin",)



                         public String saveWithVersionAttachement(File file,String oldId, String name, String folderName, String userName, String pwd)
        throws Exception {
 .............
 .............
```

in my opinion this method must save the new file in alfresco like this test_2.pdf or test_v2.pdf ..

so the two files are saved in alfresco and having the same id

and in the download method  I want to have the latest version.

so I must change the method `getContentById ("d7633eff-8595-4d6c-8c18-a29a656607ba", "admin", "admin");`

in order to return the latest version which is **test_2.pdf or test_v2.pdf ...**

I tried unsuccessfully to work with OpenCMIS using **alfresco-OpenCMIS-extension-0.7.jar**

I added this lines in **Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\model\contentModel.xml**

```
<mandatory-aspects>
<aspect>cm:versionable</aspect>
</mandatory-aspects>
```

also I added   this line `version.store.enableAutoVersioning=true`

in **Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco-global.properties**

is there anyone who can help me to solve my problem

**UPDATED :**

**I work with CMIS :**

I try with this code :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Document;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Repository;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.SessionFactory;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.SessionParameter;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.ContentStream;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BindingType;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;


     public void saveVersioning(File file, String filename, String userName, String pwd, String docId)
            throws Exception {

            SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // User credentials.
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.USER,userName);
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, pwd);

            // Connection settings.
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:9080/alfresco/service/cmis"); // URL to your CMIS server.
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.AUTH_HTTP_BASIC, "true" );

            // Create session.
            // Alfresco only provides one repository.
            Repository repository = factory.getRepositories(parameters).get(0);

            Session session = repository.createSession();

             // Get the contents of the file
            Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(docId);
            ContentStream contentStream = doc.getContentStream(); // returns null if the document has no content
            if (contentStream != null) {


                    String mimetype = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
                    String content = "";

                    if (contentStream != null) {
                        filename = contentStream.getFileName();
                        mimetype = contentStream.getMimeType();
                        content = getContentAsString(contentStream);
                        System.out.println("file name "+filename);
                        System.out.println("minetype "+mimetype);
                        System.out.println("content "+content);
                    }


                    byte[] buf = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));
                    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);

                    contentStream = session.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(
                            filename, buf.length, mimetype, input);



                    System.out.println("Document version history");
                    {
                        List<Document> versions = doc.getAllVersions();
                        for (Document version : versions) {
                            System.out.println("\tname: " + version.getName());
                            System.out.println("\tversion label: " + version.getVersionLabel());
                            System.out.println("\tversion series id: " + version.getVersionSeriesId());
                            System.out.println("\tchecked out by: "
                                    + version.getVersionSeriesCheckedOutBy());
                            System.out.println("\tchecked out id: "
                                    + version.getVersionSeriesCheckedOutId());
                            System.out.println("\tmajor version: " + version.isMajorVersion());
                            System.out.println("\tlatest version: " + version.isLatestVersion());
                            System.out.println("\tlatest major version: " + version.isLatestMajorVersion());
                            System.out.println("\tcheckin comment: " + version.getCheckinComment());
                            System.out.println("\tcontent length: " + version.getContentStreamLength()
                                    + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }



        }



    private static String getContentAsString(ContentStream stream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream.getStream(), "UTF-8");

        try {
            final char[] buffer = new char[4 * 1024];
            int b;
            while (true) {
                b = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (b > 0) {
                    sb.append(buffer, 0, b);
                } else if (b == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I call this fonction using this code :

```
File file = new File("C:/version/test.pdf");

saveVersioning(file, "test.pdf","admin","admin","d7633eff-8595-4d6c-8c18-a29a656607ba");
```

I used this jar :

```
chemistry-opencmis-client-api-0.13.0.jar
chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.13.0.jar
chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-0.13.0.jar
chemistry-opencmis-commons-api-0.13.0.jar
chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl-0.13.0.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.0.jar
```

but when I try to test  I have this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/SessionFactory
.............
............
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.SessionFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    ... 124 more
```

Comment: Why are you using the old WebServices stuff? Why not use the modern and properly supported CMIS? https://www.alfresco.com/cmis

Comment: thank you för your reply, Ï will try tô work with CMIS. Ï downloaded chemistry-opencmis-commons-api-0.4.0.jar.   is someone could help me to save document with version and download the latest version using CMIS

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and **easiest** way to achieve that is to leverage the [RESTfull API](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html)

This will also ensure compatibility with new versions of alfresco.

Note that you need to provide the noderef for the document to update in the form property *updatenoderef* and that the property *majorversion* is a boolean flag to specify if the new version is a minor/major version of the document.

Here is a sample code that might help you with your usecase:

```
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(<alfresco-service-uri>+"/api/upload?alf_ticket="+<al-ticket>);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addTextBody("username", "<username>", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addTextBody("updatenoderef", <noderef>, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addTextBody("...", "...", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addBinaryBody("filedata", <InputStream>, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, <filename>);
        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();

        uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);

        String responseString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"); 
        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200){
            throw new Exception("Couldn't upload file to the repository, webscript response :" + responseString );
        }
```

**Note 1:** You need to replace these tockens <*> with your own values/vars

**Note 2:** If you have problem retrieving a ticket, check [this link](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-RepositoryLoginGet.html), or [this one](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-RepositoryLoginPost.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the versioning as you already did, you need only to update the document with the new binary and the new name. Alfresco will take care of the versioning. The get method will retrieve the last version.

[This link describes how to update a document using CMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html#updating-a-document)

I do not think that you need to modify the get method.

Comment: thank you for your response , I have updated my question ,I try without success to use cmis in my code

Comment: You are importing and using the class org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.SessionFactory. For what I can see in the stack trace it seems that you are not linking this class when you execute the client. The class is contained in chemistry-opencmis-client-api-0.13.0.jar so be sure that you add it to the classpath.

Comment: Of course, sorry if you are already including this jar... it does not seem so based on the error returned.