# Change content of file - Alfresco

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have an `Custom Document Library Action` to `Alfresco` files, and when I press this button opens a new page with an applet (javascript) to make changes to a file, but I'm doing the modifications in `base64` and to "appear" on the screen with this :

```
var stringPDF = "<object data=\"data:application/pdf;base64," +
JSON.parse(pdfbase64).message + "\"
type=\"application/pdf\"width=\"100%\"
height=\"100%\"></object>";$("#pdfTexto").html(stringPDF);
```

But I really need is to change the file, for when the repository again, there have to change, not just display. How do I change the existing file's contents to the new with the change?

I use this URL to make GET of the file:

> http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/21384098-19dc-4d3f-bcc1-9fdc647c05dc/latexexemplo.pdf

Then I convert to the base64... And I make the changes...

But if I want to make a POST to change the content, how can I make this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the Rest api and Ajax from Javascript to post the changes to the file to Alfresco.

Comment: @matthewp. a post to this url http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/4fb1b7e7-2502-4011-8870-17e8d626b93b/pdf.pdf that i make the get too?

Comment: @matthewp. if you can give me an example please. How can i change content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentionned in [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34587787/2307988) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34575960/2307988) :

> The fastest and **easiest** way to achieve that is to leverage the [RESTfull API](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html)
>
> This will also ensure compatibility with new versions of alfresco.
>
> Note that you need to provide the noderef for the document to update in the form property *updatenoderef* and that the property *majorversion* is a boolean flag to specify if the new version is a minor/major version of the document.
>
> Here is a sample code that might help you with your usecase:
>
> ```
>         CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
>         HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(<alfresco-service-uri>+"/api/upload?alf_ticket="+<al-ticket>);
>
>         MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
>         builder.addTextBody("username", "<username>", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
>         builder.addTextBody("updatenoderef", <noderef>, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
>         builder.addTextBody("...", "...", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
>         builder.addBinaryBody("filedata", <InputStream>, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, <filename>);
>         HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
>
>         uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
>
>         CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
>
>         String responseString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"); 
>         JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
>         if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200){
>             throw new Exception("Couldn't upload file to the repository, webscript response :" + responseString );
>         }
> ```
>
> **Note 1:** You need to replace these tockens <*> with your own values/vars
>
> **Note 2:** If you have problem retrieving a ticket, check [this link](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-RepositoryLoginGet.html), or [this one](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-RepositoryLoginPost.html)

**Note 3:** To do this in JavaScript instead of java, visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and try to use js to post the parameters I referred as instructed !

**Note 4:** Since you are working on share, you are most probably authenticated.

If it is the case, you can access your alfresco repo through the proxy endpoint in share and all requests will have authentication ticket attached to them before getting forwarded to your repo !

In other terms, use this endpoint :

```
/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload
```

Instead of :

```
/alfresco/service/api/upload
```

and You won't even have to attach a ticket to your requests.

Comment: I can made this in javascript?

Comment: check my 3rd note ;-)

Comment: I just have one more question: I have the applet loaded but how do I get the username and password without asking again the user for it? So defining your first Note with a username and password different for each user.

Comment: And another question, I made the changes on PDF in b64, but where I put this changes on request? To update the content of the file?

On my code above, pdfbase64 is the pdf with the changes. Where I include this on your code? I'm confused with this part.

Comment: @PRVS: Since you are working on share, you are most probably authenticated.

If it is the case, you can access your alfresco repo through the proxy endpoint in share and all requests will have authentication ticket attached to them before getting forwarded to your repo !

In other terms, use this endpoint :

    /share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload
Instead of :

    /alfresco/service/api/upload

and You won't even have to attach a ticket to your requests !

Comment: Ok, so, i don't need <al-ticket> right, in your code?
And <username> and password i don't need username header too, right?

For the question of update content of PDF (put the changes on request), you can give me a hint for this?

Comment: You do not need username and password anymore, the first time I saw your question I failed to notice that you are using share ....
I didn't understand your last question

Comment: Ok thanks for the first reply. 
I try to explain :) 
I have base64 pdf variable that has content encoded in base64. However, I do not know how to send that content (base64pdf) to modify the contents of existing file. This is, replace the PDF content that is in the alfresco with a certain nodeRef with the contents of this variable (base64pdf). That is what I intend to do. 
I don't know where to put this on your code.

Comment: First, examine [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html) to know what you should be passing exactly to your requestion in order to upload a new revision of your file. Second, you need to pass on your data using `FormData` in JS, if you are not familiar with it, you can check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)! Your form data should at least contain `updatenoderef`, `username` and `filedata`; Besides, your file should have the versionable aspect or you will need to pass `overwrite` parameter as well

Comment: But filedata is the name of the file that i want to update right? 
So, where I put the content? I read the http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html parameters, in this link, and i don't understand that part.

Comment: @PRVS: no! filedata is for the file content, no need to reference your file name nor file path ... etc, since you identified your file uniquely by it's noderef `updatenoderef`

Comment: Ohhh! So, for the filedata, if I understand in a search on the Internet is "file from file browser which needs to be uploaded ", but I made the changes on the applet and i put on the variable (base64pdf), if i put this base64pdf on this parameter, it not works, right? I have to create a temporary file locally with changes ? I think this is not good solution :( Any advice?

Comment: you understand my question? I need this help.

Comment: @PRVS: why wouldn't it work ? why do you need to create a local file?? just make sure to base64 decode it in case it is base64 encoded as the variable name suggests !
Next time try experimenting possiblities on a test instance instead of asking for a ready solutions !

Comment: My problem for solve this, now, is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975107/alfresco-update-file-error-post

Comment: @PRVS: if my answer did help you with your issue, please accept it!

Comment: I put a Bounty because i want to reach the final objective. Make the post and Update the document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps to achieve what you are looking for.

**1) Reading File:**

To display content of PDF file already uploaded you need to read content of file. You are able to do it successfully using following API call.

> http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/21384098-19dc-4d3f-bcc1-9fdc647c05dc/latexexemplo.pdf

**2) Capture New Content:**

Capture new file content from User from applet. I guess you are storing it in some String variable.

**3) Edit Existing File Content:**

Issue here is that you cannot simply edit any pdf file using any of out of box Alfresco REST API (as far as I know). So you need to create your own RESTFul API which could edit pdf file's content. You can consider using some third party libraries to do this job. You need to plugin logic of editing pdf in RESTFul API

**4) Changes back to Repo:**
  Call Your API from Step 3:

You could also have look at this plugins which could fulfill your requirements.

https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-pdf-toolkit

Hope this helps.

Comment: But i don't know how to make the "3)" . I have this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975107/alfresco-update-file-error-post